# Meaning of “Matching clothing can also present problems as can decorating house.”

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the sentence in bold:

“In fact, due to the high rate of color blindness in society web designer have started to take this into account. **Matching clothing can also present problems as can decorating house**.”

Comment: "...can present problems _to colour-blind people_" is implied.

Comment: “In fact, due to the high rate of color blindness in society, web designers have started to take this into account. Matching clothing can also present problems as can decorating houses.” Seems like there are some missing plurals, not sure whether it is a typo.

Comment: It seems as if the color-blind people might be happy enough with their choices. It's the others would would find them problematic.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a minor problem with the sentence. It appears to be missing an article or determiner in "decorating house". Most English speakers would say "decorating *the* house", or "decorating *their* house".

The context is talking about *colour-blind persons* - that is people who cannot perceive colours properly, if at all.

The sentence you are asking about highlights two things that are difficult for the colour-blind: (i) matching clothes, and (ii) decorating their home.

"Matching clothes" means choosing clothes that match one another.

"Decorating (their) home" refers to things like wallpapering, painting etc which involves making choices about colours and patterns that match or compliment each other.